# Disable automatic screen turn-off in Android during call

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a service which launches a "BroadcastReceiver" after the user has finished booting (ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and when the device goes to sleep (ACTION_SCREEN_OFF). My "BroadcastReceiver" checks when an incoming call is received (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) and launches a "Service" that records the call. It is working but the problem is that my device turn off display during call when I put the phone to my ear, so the service launches again the "BroadcastReceiver". Is there someone who knows how to solve it?

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should'nt be possible, because the telephone app is in the forground and is triggering the display if it detects an proximity near event. You can maybe set a wakelock and release this afterwards.